# Riemann Integral doesn't change due to a change in functional value

Tags: calculus

Prove that the value of the Riemann Integral doesn't change if we change the value of the given continuous function at finite number of points.
Let $f(x)$ be a given continuous function on $[a, b]$ and let at $x=p$ where $p$ lies in $(a, b)$ we chage the functional value such that the new function is $g(x)$
Now the original Riemann sum was $$f(c_0)\Delta x_0+f(c_1)\Delta x_1+....f(c_{p-1})\Delta x_{p-1}+........+f(c_{n-1})\Delta x_{n-1}$$ where $f(c_{p-1})$ is the functional value in the $(p-1)th$ subinterval Now the reimann sum of $g(x)$ over $[a, b]$ is same as of $f(x)$ except if we choose $c_k=x_p$ in $[x_{p-1}, x_p]$ Now even if we take the value $c_k=x_p$ in $[x_{p-1}, x_p]$ then the Riemann sum for $g(x)$ and for $f(x)$ will converge to the same limit as $\Delta x_{max} \to 0$ because the term $f(c_{p-1})\Delta x_{p-1}$ has no contribution individually as $\Delta x_{max} \to 0$ So the Riemann sum of $g(x)$ over $[a, b]$ will also converge to the same limit
IS MY PROOF CORRECT?

Answer (score 1):

- The theorem requests to change the function at a finite number of points.  The proof considers a function changed at only one point.  There is a gap between one point and finitely many points.
- Every term in the sum individually contributes, including any term from the changed point.  If you want to show that the term potentially coming from the changed point is eventually negligible, you should have already chosen an $\varepsilon$ to bound the magnitude of that contribution.
- It is not clear from this proof whether changing the value at one point has ruined existence of the limit along refinements of the partition.  Even if the limit exists, it is not clear that the limit has not changed due to the altered contribution from the changed point.

In order to match the hypotheses, the proof should probably start with something like

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and $g$ be a function that agree with $f$ on $[a,b]$ except for finitely many points, $p_1$, $p_2$, $\dots$, $p_k$.

You might benefit from thinking about $\int_a^b f(x) - g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$, which has a fairly easy to guess value, so it is easier to see if altering the $p_i$ changes it.

Comment: But as the limit of $f(c_0)\Delta x_0+f(c_1)\Delta x_1+.........+f(c_{p-1})\Delta x_{p-1}+........+f(c_{n-1})\Delta x_{n-1}$ as $\Delta x_{max} \to 0$ exists as $f(x)$ is continuous and as the limit of $f(c_{p-1})\Delta x_{p-1}$ is $0$ so the limit of the whole Riemann sum without this term also exists and remains unchanged

Comment: @PranavaPriyanshu : Then you should have no trouble showing that the difference of these two sums is less than any small $\varepsilon > 0$ an adversary proposes.

Comment: @PranavaPriyanshu : And how does this argument change when you have $k$ many points of disagreement?  We cannot just announce that we are free to ignore arbitrarily many terms of the sum without some justification that ignoring those terms *collectively* produces a difference that vanishes in the limit.